# ASP.net C# Log4net not working. Properties folder missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

I had a working log4net which stopped working after I rearranged my sheets into folders. Then everything wen crazy. The log4net was not recognized anymore. I added some xml from a tutorial and then the errors stopped. The logging didn't start though. I have decided to scrap everything. I have deleted all traces of log4net and am following [this](http://hanskindberg.wordpress.com/2013/04/07/log4net-configuration/) tutorial now.
Stuck at step one though. :( I do not have a properties folder or my assemblyinfo.cs file.

[Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwgxD.png)

Please help me with this logging functionality.

Comment: I suggest you to use NLog instead of Log4net.
Nlog is very easy to use and lots of stuff you can do it and more flexible then Log4net

Comment: I need to use log4net as that is being deployed in the main project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add a properties folder and `AssemblyInfo.cs` file? Create a new project and copy the default `AssemblyInfo.cs` file from there as a template.  Or you could add the `XmlConfigurator.Configure();` statement to your `Application_Start` method in `global.asax.cs`.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}
```

Comment: I tried adding a new project. That didn't have a Properties folder either.

Comment: Error 1 :The name 'XmlConfigurator' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @divinediu you'd need to add log4net to the project and add `using log4net.Config` or reference it using the fully qualified namespace, `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();`

Comment: @divinediu - or you could simply search GitHub for a template you like, https://github.com/search?l=csharp&q=AssemblyInfo.cs&ref=searchresults&type=Code

Comment: I did that. Ran the project. Now what?

Comment: @divinediu That should take care of configuring it without need for the AssemblyInfo.cs file. You should be able to follow the rest of the tutorial now.

Comment: I tried [this](http://www.justinrhinesmith.com/blog/2008/05/12/quick-and-easy-log4net-setup/) no error. But then no logfile in C:/ either. :(

Comment: go through https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial
best tutorial for Nlog @divinediu